# Directing url request to a subfolder on ubuntu server

Tags: redirect, ubuntu, apache2, httpd.conf

Here is the task 
When user enters in browser `domain.com/something/something`,
get files not from `domain.com/something/something` as was expected, but from

```
domain.com/something/something/www
```

In my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder I've found domain.com.conf

And it contains only this

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
</virtualhost>
```

So how should I edit my domain.com.conf file ?

Comment: what have you got configured in your httpd.conf?

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirecting url from one subfolder to another using conf file / ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982145/redirecting-url-from-one-subfolder-to-another-using-conf-file-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path.

- If you have only one domain

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default modify the line :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/www/
```

And then restart apache :

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

This will change the path for the default host.

- If you have several domains

You need VirtualHosts. If you have already VirtualHosts, you probably have multiple files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/, find the one managing your domain. Otherwise create one from default by `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com`. It should contains something like this at the begining :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

   ServerName domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/www/
   <Directory /var/www/domain/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

....many stuff

</VirtualHost>
```

Then enable the site and restart apache :

```
$ sudo a2ensite domain.com
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

- If you just want that a particular path /something/something/ be served from /domain.com/something/something/www/, set up an alias :

`Alias /something/something /something/something/www`

Comment: Hey Royer thanks for the help, I think that's the right way to do it, except I've edited my problem, it's a bit specific. can you edit you post according to my needs ?
p.s. thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure about your question : you have a www directory in each directory, or you just want that one directory would be redirect to /thedirectory/www/ ?

Comment: I've made another question with better review of my problem, because nobody was looking into this one anymore.
Please have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982145/redirecting-url-from-one-subfolder-to-another-using-conf-file-ubuntu

Comment: great tutorial on this here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts