# redirecting url from one subfolder to another using conf file / ubuntu

Tags: apache, redirect, configuration, httpd.conf

I have web site on `domain.com`
which is located at `/var/www/main`

I also have started another web site which I want to be on url `domain.com/a/b`
But the actual file location is `/var/www/main/a/b/c`

Problem is that I want the users to use url `domain.com/a/b` and get files from `/var/www/main/a/b/c`

So I've found domains conf file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.conf`

It had only this

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
</virtualhost>
```

Now after reading different topics about it I've tried to add this so now my domain.com.conf file looks like this

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerPath /a/b/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main/a/b/c
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(/a/b/.*) /var/www/main/a/b/c
    # ...
</virtualhost>
```

But this does not work at all.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for Rewrite Rules. Just set up an alias in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.conf` :

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    Alias /a/b /var/www/main/a/b/c
</virtualhost>
```

Then restart apache :

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing opens' ?

Comment: The requested URL /a/b was not found on this server.

Comment: Woops check my edit. There was a mistake in Alias line.